# how to initialize python class variables based on a parameter without using self?

Tags: python, initialization, class-variables, python-class, class-attributes

In the folloewing code piece, I want class variable x get value 1000, but it didn't, it gets 'None'.

```
class G:     
    dat = None
    x = dat
    y = dat+2

    def __init__(self, pdat) -> None:
        G.dat = pdat


    
g = G(1000)
print(g.dat, 'g.x', g.x, 'G.x',G.x)
```

the result is:
1000 g.x None G.x None

What I really want is to define x, y based on parameter pdat.

But I don't want to use self prefix, e.g.:

```
 def __init__(self, pdat) -> None:
        self.x = pdat
```

any idea?

Comment: Try printing G.dat instead of G.x. Creating a G instance doesn't update G.x, only G.dat.

Comment: The actual result I get running this code is a TypeError on line 4. You can't add 2 to None.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, which makes it more difficult to answer your question. Are you saying that you want dat, x and y to change every time an instance of G is created - all existing G's would see the new values?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> g = G(1000)
> print(g.dat, 'g.x', g.x, 'G.x',G.x)
> ```

When you create `g` you update `G.dat`. But you don't update `G.x`. `G.dat` and `G.x` are two separate objects, and they aren't mutable objects, so changing one won't affect the other.

If you want to see that the class objects are changed, print out `G.dat` instead of `G.x`.